# Dynamic filter in PivotTable based on the system date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, date, system-date

I have a pivot table in Excel 2016.

In the PivotTable, I want to create a filter on the data's YEAR column so that only records where the YEAR is between `this year` and `this year + 9` are used in the PivotTable.

Something like this:

[image]

---

**Hardcoding options:**

I'm aware that I could use a hardcoded filter in the Label Filter:

[image]

Or I could do the hardcoding in the *field filter* in the sheet:

[image]

But I would prefer to use dynamic values based on the system date, rather than relying on people to manually update the hardcoded filter...on January 1st each year.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to create a dynamic filter in a PivotTable based on the system date?

Comment: A really easy solution would be to add a helper column to the source data which returns true/false (or 1,0 or whatever) depending on whether the date is in the desired range. Put TODAY() in a cell somewhere and refer to it with a named range in the folrmulas, rather than using it directly.
If your source data is brought in via PowerQuery you could do this as a transform step instead.
Then filter on this column and just leave Year in the row labels for the PT

Comment: @AdamV Good idea. Thanks.